# how can i add today's date to the .htaccess log file name

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I would like to combine today's date to the php errors log files

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag  log_errors on
    php_value error_log  logs/php_errors_%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}.log
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you can't. Use an external log rotater. Apache comes with one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php_value error_log "|/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs /home/test/public_html/logs/failures_%Y-%m-%d.log 8600"
```